How to prevent // breaking after http links?
i am using \uri{...} for url link. I want to prevent // breaking after http links? Below is my reference code:
\bibitem{bib.bib15}
\hypertarget{bib.bib15}{}\cvotag{[15]} \bibtyp{other}  \bibgnm{Eberhard}, \bibgnm{David} \bibsnm{M.}, \bibgnm{Gary F.} \bibsnm{Simons}, and \bibgnm{Charles D.} \bibsnm{Fennig} (Eds.). \bibyrs{2021}. \textit{\bibatl{Sign Language}}. Retrieved from \uri{https://www.ethnologue.com/subgroups/sign-language}

and the output is


As always here please provide a full but minimal exmaple others can copy and test as is. It might seem tedious for you, but it is the only way we can not exactly what you are doing. For examly I do not remember ever seeing a bibitem formatted that way. If the url package is loaded then / is a valid breakpoint.

You can always use a \mbox{...} to prevent a line break.

your image shows it breaking after : not after //  (it's a lot easier to stop breaking after : than it is to stop it after // while allowing a break at a single /.

how is \uri defined?

@daleif, i just want to prevent // breaking after `http:' any places.

@UlrikeFischer, the \uri is defined in uri package
[https://ctan.org/pkg/uri?lang=en]

@DavidCarlisle - Yes you are correct. Is there any way to control automatically throughout article.
